# Using Greenshot external command to send a gmail with an attachment

Tags: email, powershell, gmail

I'm trying to setup an external command in Greenshot (a free screen capture tool) that will take the screen capture and send it to myself via gmail. I can run a command from the powershell console using the Send-MailMessage and get it working correctly. But I can't seem to get it working from within Greenshot.

Attached is a screenshot of the external command conifgure dialogue in greenshot.

[image]

The command line holds the path to my powershell.exe executable.

My current argument box holds the value:

```
"-Command "& G:\Users\<user name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\SendMail.ps1" "{0}""
```

SendMail.ps1 is a simple script with a single command:

```
$attachment = $args[0];

Send-MailMessage -smtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Credential $mycredentials -from 'myself@gmail.com' -to 'myself@gmail.com' -subject 'Screen Capture' -UseSsl true -Attachments $attachment
```

I don't really know how to debug it as I'm not very experience. There is no output, and even if I use the -NoExit option it just opens a powershell window to a command prompt with no output there either.

Comment: Try using ProcessMonitor to debug the exact syntax being passed to Greenshot - http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-processmonitor-to-debug-command.html

Comment: FYI..
..G:\Users\<user name>\Documents..
Can be updated to:
..G:\Users\$env:username\Documents..

Or..
$username=$env:username
..G:\Users\$username\Documents..

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got some quotes missing, but rather than fix it to use the Command parameter, I would use the File parameter:

```
-File "G:\Users\<user name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\SendMail.ps1" "{0}"
```

Also, `UseSsl` is a flag. You don't need "true" after it.